# Can't create Firebase Cloud Messages From Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

For some reason, I don't see the ability for me to create FCMs from the Firebase console. It's not a browser issue as I tried on multiple browsers. It's not a permissions issue either since I am the owner of the project.

I tried implementing cloud functions to send FCMs and ever since when I go into the Cloud Messaging panel of the Firebase console I can no longer see the option to create messages.

Any insight would help!

[image]

Update--This is the error I'm getting from the JavaScript console:
[image]

Comment: Hmmm... that looks odd. Can you try disabling all extensions in your browser (especially ad blockers)? If that doesn't help, can you try in a different browser? If that also doesn't work, can you check for error messages in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: Hi Frank, the javascript console is giving us some clues! I've updated the original post with the errors. I'm not sure why there is an auth error, it doesn't seem to be something I can solve by logging in and out again.